# How to deal with multiple sub resources in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cdi

I have a JAX-RS REST API with several sub resources e.g.

`users/{user_id}/posts/{post_id}/comments/{comment_id}`. The resources are divided into individual classes (`UsersResource`, `UserResource`, `PostsResource`, etc.) and accessed via sub resource locators. Each resource uses a correlating service (`UserService`, `PostService`, `CommentService`) to access the database.

How would I go about realising this? I tried to search for an example but was only able to find very basic ones.

I already implemented several approaches but they all "feel" wrong.

One was to inject all services in the root resource and pass them along. But it seems wasteful to instantiate all services although only the first might be needed.

Another was to make all resources `@RequestScoped` and inject the subsequent resource so the right service can be injected at the right place. But I would need to inject the sub resource in advance even if I didn't need it and I wouldn't be able to pass parameters along.

My current approach fails at not being able to inject the service inside my sub resource. (see below)

`root resource (resources/users)`

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("users")
public class UsersResource() {

    @Inject
    private UserService service;

    @Path("{user_id}")
    public UserResource getUserResource(@Context ResourceContext context, @PathParam("user_id") Long id) {
        User entity = this.service.find(id);

        if (entity == null)
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build());

        return context.initResource(new UserResource(entity, this.service));
    }
}
```

`user sub resource (resources/users/{user_id})`

```
public class UserResource() {

    private User entity;
    private UserService service;

    public UserResource(User entity, UserService service) {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GET
    public Response doGet() {
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }

    @Path("posts")
    public TodosResource getPostsResource(@Context ResourceContext context) {
        return context.initResource(new PostsResource(entity));
    }
}
```

`posts sub resource (resources/users/{user_id}/posts)`

```
public class PostsResource() {

    @Inject // can't inject here
    private PostService service;

    private User user;

    public PostsResource(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @POST
    public Response doPost(@Context UriInfo info, Post post) {
        post.setUser(this.user);
        Post entity = this.service.persist(post);
        URI uri = info.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path("/" + entity.getId()).build();

        return Response.created(uri).entity(entity).build();
    }

    @Path("{post_id}")
    public PostResource getpostResource(@Context ResourceContext context, @PathParam("post_id") Long id) {
        Post entity = this.service.find(id);

        if (entity == null)
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build());

        return context.initResource(new PostResource(entity));
    }
```

service example

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    (...)
}
```

Comment: Looking at how you've set it up, I can't help but feel that you've overcomplicated the set-up itself. I would have created an overall "API" resource at the level of UsersResource, and injected all the services at that level, and then mapped the contents of the sub-resources at this level as well.

Comment: My reason was just that I didn't want to instantiate them if I didn't have to. The root resource would have to create an instance for every possible service even if the request was meant for the root itself.

Comment: The idea behind using multiple services in one resource isn't that you'll need them all now, but you'll definitely need them all at some point down the road, so having them ready to go when they're needed. Your server will run a singular instance of your UsersResource for all users, but at the moment, you're proposing to serve up short-lived UserResource and PostResource on a per-call basis, which will go out of scope once they're done, which is significantly more costly than keeping a single Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but the answer to this is still hard to find.

To Inject EJBs directly in subresources, annotate the subresource with @Provider, it could also be a good idea to append @Produces.

So your

```
public class PostsResource() {
```

becomes

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PostsResource() {
```